# How to access the driver from main method into another method

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

In below code, I want to access the driver from main method to another method inside same class. To clear the error i put 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); inside the another method??. Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance for your time

```
    public class FramesSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) Exception
    {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("url");
    //TODO stuff
    new FramesSample().switchToFrame("parentid", "childid");

    }
    public void switchToFrame(String ParentFrame, String ChildFrame)
    {
    try {
    driver.switchTo().frame(ParentFrame).switchTo().frame(ChildFrame)
    //TODO Stuff
   }
   }
```

Comment: Move driver out of the main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it out at class level like this.

Also make it static as you are calling it from static main method.

```
public class FramesSample {

static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();     <-------

    public static void main(String[] args) Exception
    {

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("url");
    //TODO stuff
    new FramesSample().switchToFrame("parentid", "childid");

    }
    public void switchToFrame(String ParentFrame, String ChildFrame)
    {
    try {
    driver.switchTo().frame(ParentFrame).switchTo().frame(ChildFrame)
    //TODO Stuff
   }
   }
```